# How i can run multiple asp.net core web api in different node on local service fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have a stateless web application used as frontend, A statefull webapi(want to use as gateway) application and two stateless application. I want to run all the service in different node on my local service fabric cluster.

How to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToDosScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ToDosScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Todos'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            Row(
              children: const [
                Expanded(flex: 1, child: Icon(Icons.list_alt_outlined)),
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('Kegiatan')),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 9,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: 'Judul Kegiatan',
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: const [
                Expanded(flex: 1, child: Icon(Icons.subject)),
                Expanded(flex: 11, child: Text('Keterangan')),
              ],
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Tambah Keterangan',
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 50, 8, 50)),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    flex: 6,
                    child: Row(
                      children: const [
                        Expanded(flex: 4, child: Icon(Icons.date_range)),
                        Expanded(flex: 8, child: Text('Tanggal Mulai')),
                      ],
                    )),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 6,
                    child: Row(
                      children: const [
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 4, child: Icon(Icons.date_range_outlined)),
                        Expanded(flex: 8, child: Text('Tanggal Selesai')),
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                          child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                            hintText: '20-03-2022',
                          )))),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                          child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                            hintText: '20-03-2022',
                          )))),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    flex: 6,
                    child: Expanded(
                        flex: 4,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                //
                              },
                              child: const Text('Batal'),
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  minimumSize: const Size(100, 40)),
                            )))),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 6,
                    child: Expanded(
                        flex: 4,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                //
                              },
                              child: const Text('Simpan'),
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  minimumSize: const Size(100, 40),
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white),
                            )))),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```